# dbms_output.put_line not working after the insert

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a 20000 lines of code in a PL/SQL package. The package is working fine. I wished to debug my code for the variables, which I have used inside the package. For that I have used `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`, however, the output is not getting displayed after the insert statement.

Consider the error code

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BEFORE INSERT');

INSERT INTO TEST (ID,NAME) VALUES(1,'ORACLE');

COMMIT;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AFTER INSERT');
```

The serveroutput is only returning the output "BEFORE INSERT". The values got inserted in the table, but the message "AFTER INSERT" is not being displayed. Any particular reason?

I have increased the server output value to 100000 too without changing the behaviour

Comment: did you call `set serveroutput on`?

Comment: Yeah i did   set serveroutput on size 1000000 ;

Comment: It's trivially provable that this works with the context given. You need to provide a minimal example that demonstrates what your issue is. Also, all the code is currently commented out...

Comment: I agree with Raj_Te, it could be dropping out via a `when others` exception handler. Maybe it's time to use an actual debugger.

Comment: As Ben also noticed, the code is between /* ... */. It will never run as a comment.

Comment: @AnishGopinath..I had formatted your code so that it could had made some sense but since you didnot inline my formatting, now your code is not correct. Everything is in comment so PLSQL is working correct.

Comment: Yeah Raj_Te, the entire pl/sql block was working fine, Even i tried taking the insert query and executed separately it inserting perfectly without errors

Comment: Sorry about the mis communication, please take out the comment sign. The code is just  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(before insert) insert query the dbms output(after insert)

Comment: So... if everything is working fine, why do you need to debug? This makes no sense from the outset. I asume the code is not working fine; if it did, you wouldn't need to debug it.

Comment: (a) are you sure it's even reaching this code; and (b) is anything in your code doing `dbms_output.disable` - even after these calls?

Answer (score 0):

This will return both **BEFORE INSERT** and **AFTER INSERT**.

```
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BEFORE INSERT');
insert into TEST values(1,'ORACLE');
commit;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AFTER INSERT');
end;
/
```